# On Ubuntu 16.04, v8 build error

Tags: google-chrome, v8

```
asiagaming@ubuntu:~/v8/v8$ make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/asiagaming/v8/v8/out'
  TOUCH bdc92efe44eca1954fdff70fd086c7e138d0fbb1.intermediate
  ACTION Generating inspector protocol sources from protocol json bdc92efe44eca1954fdff70fd086c7e138d0fbb1.intermediate
  CXX(target) /home/asiagaming/v8/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/v8_base/gen/src/inspector/protocol/Protocol.o
In file included from /home/asiagaming/v8/v8/out/ia32.release/obj/gen/src/inspector/protocol/Protocol.cpp:7:
In file included from /home/asiagaming/v8/v8/out/ia32.release/obj/gen/src/inspector/protocol/Protocol.h:8:
In file included from /home/asiagaming/v8/v8/out/ia32.release/obj/gen/src/inspector/protocol/Forward.h:8:
.././src/inspector/string-util.h:8:10: fatal error: 'memory' file not found
#include <memory>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
src/v8_base.target.ia32.release.mk:750: recipe for target '/home/asiagaming/v8/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/v8_base/gen/src/inspector/protocol/Protocol.o' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/asiagaming/v8/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/v8_base/gen/src/inspector/protocol/Protocol.o] Error 1
rm bdc92efe44eca1954fdff70fd086c7e138d0fbb1.intermediate
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/asiagaming/v8/v8/out'
Makefile:319: recipe for target 'ia32.release' failed
make: *** [ia32.release] Error 2
```

I've tried to build V8 engine, but above error msg is printed.
How to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Does `sudo apt-get install build-essential` help?

(Side note: Simply invoking `make` is probably not what you want. Check out https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building-with-GN.)

Comment: Are you asking a question and commenting in the Answer section or is that supposed to be an answer?

Comment: It's an answer if it helps. My guess is that it helps, but we won't know until we hear back from the OP. If you think you can give a more helpful answer, go right ahead ;-)